# Compiling MPI with make, several namespace errors such as "error: unknown type name ‘using’?

Tags: c++, makefile, namespaces, mpi

I'm trying to compile MPI on Xubuntu 16.04 LTS and I'm quite positive I have all of my g++ and gcc includes and libraries already installed and yet I get this weird mess...

```
    make[3]: Entering directory '/media/verthex/32gig/openmpi-3.1.2/oshmem/shmem/c/profile'
  LN_S     pshmem_init.c
  CC       pshmem_init.lo
In file included from ../../../../oshmem/include/shmem.h:26:0,
                 from ../../../../oshmem/include/oshmem/constants.h:15,
                 from pshmem_init.c:22:
/usr/local/include/complex.h:10:1: error: unknown type name ‘using’
 using namespace std;
 ^
/usr/local/include/complex.h:10:17: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘std’
 using namespace std;
                 ^
/usr/local/include/complex.h:13:17: fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:1950: recipe for target 'pshmem_init.lo' failed
make[3]: *** [pshmem_init.lo] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/media/verthex/32gig/openmpi-3.1.2/oshmem/shmem/c/profile'
Makefile:2012: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/media/verthex/32gig/openmpi-3.1.2/oshmem/shmem/c'
Makefile:2578: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/media/verthex/32gig/openmpi-3.1.2/oshmem'
Makefile:1897: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

This is the configure output towards the end.

```
Open MPI configuration:
-----------------------
Version: 3.1.2
Build MPI C bindings: yes
Build MPI C++ bindings (deprecated): no
Build MPI Fortran bindings: no
MPI Build Java bindings (experimental): no
Build Open SHMEM support: yes
Debug build: no
Platform file: (none)

Miscellaneous
-----------------------
CUDA support: no
PMIx support: internal

Transports
-----------------------
Cisco usNIC: no
Cray uGNI (Gemini/Aries): no
Intel Omnipath (PSM2): no
Intel SCIF: no
Intel TrueScale (PSM): no
Mellanox MXM: no
Open UCX: no
OpenFabrics Libfabric: no
OpenFabrics Verbs: yes
Portals4: no
Shared memory/copy in+copy out: yes
Shared memory/Linux CMA: yes
Shared memory/Linux KNEM: no
Shared memory/XPMEM: no
TCP: yes

Resource Managers
-----------------------
Cray Alps: no
Grid Engine: no
LSF: no
Moab: no
Slurm: yes
ssh/rsh: yes
Torque: no
```

Comment: Sounds like it is trying to compile C++ code as C.

Comment: But why, I ran configure with "--prefix=/directory/to install/to" and that finished fine? Then I called make all install. I figured the makefile has this setup properly?

Comment: I added the last few lines of configure to the post. Let me know if you want the whole thing, I'll post it on pastebin.

Comment: I tried using `CXX=g++` with configure but that did work with make. Same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because, you're trying to compile a file `pshmem_init.c` which is manifestly a C file, not a C++ file.  Both make and the compiler are going to try to compile a file ending in `.c` as C, unless you go to extraordinary lengths to change their minds.

It looks to me like the C file `pshmem_init.c` is including the header `complex.h` meaning to access the standard C header, found in `/usr/include/complex.h`, but that you have added a C++ header file by that same name (`complex.h`) into `/usr/local/include`, and you've asked the compiler to look there first (it will always look in the default system directories last).

You'll have to work this out before this code will compile.

Comment: I didn't add any header, the compiler or make itself is trying to compile this thing with the include directories as installed by synaptic.  It was Synaptic that created "/usr/include/complex.h". Am I supposed to somehow specify the C include folder for configure?

Comment: Basically I have two files named complex.h. One is in `usr/local/include` and the other is in `usr/include` and also, the files are not the same, the latter one doesn't contain `#include <cmath>`?

Comment: As I said above, the one in `/usr/include`, that the file `pshmem_init.c` wants, is the standard C header (defined in the C standard).  Apparently something else is creating a `/usr/local/include/complex.h` which is a C++ header for some other program or library.  If Synaptic really did install that you can run this command to find out what package it belongs to: `dpkg -S /usr/local/include/complex.h`.  I'm a little surprised that ANY standard package would install files into `/usr/local`.

Comment: It's a terrible idea for some software to create a public header file that has the same name as any standard header, but I guess sometimes people have terrible ideas :-p :-/

Comment: I got `dpkg-query: no path found matching pattern /usr/local/include/complex.h
` for the dpkg query. Should I just delete the whole folder, or maybe create a backup and then delete it.

Comment: It seems I managed to compile and install it by deleting that `/usr/local/include` directory! I'm not exactly sure how in the world it even existed there to begin with. Thanks!

Comment: Then it was _not_ installed by Synaptic.  This doesn't surprise me because as I said, it would be extraordinarily strange for a Synaptic package to install into `/usr/local`.  Much more likely this is some package you built and installed from source: `/usr/local` is the default install location for many source packages.  Maybe you can find out what package it's a part of by looking at the file itself: does it contain a comment saying what it's for?  You can just rename the directory `sudo mv /usr/local/include /usr/local/include-old` or something.